# Finding a solution using the principle of maximum entropy?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have set of linear constraints and would like to find an answer to its unknown variables, $p_i$'s. One of my options to find  a solution for $p_i$'s using maximum entropy problem, $\max(\sum - p_i \log p_i)$. However the condition $\sum p_i=1$ does not hold. I would like to know how necessary this condition is?

I have given this problem to a solver and it converges after a few iteration, however if I divide $p_i$ by a constant to satisfy the $\sum p_i=1$ the solver fails.

Comment: How can $p_i$ represent a probability distribution if they do not sum to $1$? Can you say a little more about your model?

Comment: Actually $p_i$'s are variables, so let's not call a probability distribution.

Comment: So why do you want $\sum p_i =1$ if the $p_i$'s are variables?

Comment: You should mention that this is a continuation of your efforts in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814142/how-to-maximize-an-entropy-function). It's not a duplicate, but the relationship should still be noted.

Comment: The fact is that $\sum_i p_i = 1$ is just another linear equality constraint on the variables, like all of the others. As with any set of constraints, they are either feasible or infeasible. It sounds like your original model is feasible, but adding $\sum_i p_i=1$ makes it infeasible. It's as simple as that. Whether it is critical that $\sum_i p_i=1$ hold is up to you to decide. We can't help you there.

Comment: Having $\sum_i p_i =1$ isn't a necessary condition in my problem setting. However as I've seen in the principle of maximum entropy literature, it seems like this condition must hold in order to claim the problem as an entropy maximization problem. Is that true or not?

Comment: In other words, I have a bunch of constraints as stated in my post here, [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814142/how-to-maximize-an-entropy-function/814283?noredirect=1#comment1689323_814283) and my goal is to estimate $p_{k,i}$. To this aim, I though I can define it as an entropy maximization problem and my actuall question is whether it makes sense to do that or not?