# How to solve this entropy maximization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, entropy

I have studied different optimization techniques but found it challenging to come up with an efficient technique to solve my problem here. I am essentially looking for a computationally efficient (possibly a method with parallel execution) way to solve the following optimization problem (known as the entropy maximization):

$$min_N \sum_{ijt} N_{ij}^t log(N_{ij}^t) - N_{ij}^t $$

such that
$$ \sum_{j} N_{ij}^t = O_{i}^{t} \quad \quad \forall it $$
$$ \sum_{it} N_{ij}^t = \sum_{t} O_{j}^{t} \quad \quad \forall j $$
$$ \sum_{ij} d_{ij} N_{ij}^t = V^t \sum_{i} O_{i}^{t} \quad \quad \forall t $$

The unknown here are the $N_{ij}^t$ for all $i,j,t$. We assume that the parameters $O$, $V$ and $d$ are well known.

Comment: The reason why I am interested in a computationally efficient method is that I have a pretty large number of variables in the test case.

Comment: a similar problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814142/how-to-maximize-an-entropy-function?rq=1

Comment: Try a solver like Mosek or Ipopt. I have solved some very large instances of these entropy models with these solvers.

Comment: Additional note: interior point methods often do very well on these problems as they don't suffer from many superbasic variables.

Comment: @Kuifje yeah, I already checked that Q&A, but it's more about implementing directly the problem into a solver. I did that but it's very slow for the size of my instance. So I want to play around, e.g. relaxation, etc. before passing it to a solver.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen, looks interesting! 
I am gonna give Mosek a try as its easier to interface with Matlab which I am using to solve the problem :)

Comment: Make sure to add some bounds $N_{i,j}^t \ge 0.0001$ to protect the $\log()$ function.